# Xamarin Android+iOS builds failing on Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-devops, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an xamarin mobile app with 3 projects. Shared, Android and iOS.

All 3 build perfectly fine locally but fail on Azure Dev ops pipeline.

iOS and Android only have 2 xmal views that are platform specific. The rest are located in Shared.
For both of the xmal views, all the errors are coming from the code behind cs files complaining that something doesn't exist in the current context. There are around 80 errors like the one below. The errors are identical on both platform builds.

Example error from Droid build:

Droid\Views(Filename).xaml.cs(26,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

This build hasn't run for a while, around 8 months. It used to work fine and none of the views xmal/cs code has changed. I'm assuming a version is now misconfigured somewhere.

Both builds run on VS 2022 pipelines.
Both builds restore okay.

I have tried (Mostly suggestions from similar posts)

- Adding restore argurment to the Build step.
- Checking name spaces match
- Adding a small change (whitespace) to the 2 xmal pages to force a change.
- Removing the shared project reference and re-adding it.

I would be grateful for any suggestions or ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you typically don't have XAML files in your platform specific projects

Comment: I didn't design/build the app, and I'm unable to ask the person who did why they have done it this way. It was built before with them in this configuration so there must be a way to get this pipeline working again.

Comment: does it build locally?

Comment: Yes, can build and even deploy to a physical android device.

Answer (score 0):

In past experience, if something works locally and not on the build server pipeline; this usually points to a discrepancy between both machines, and potentially their versions of given libraries.

If you run the pipeline off of a local machine as well, maybe confirm that all libraries installed on that machine match your local ones (XCode, android-sdk, etc.)

If you run the pipeline off of a [hosted machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), it maybe that the hosted images needs to be updated to a newer one to keep up with the project.